# Django -- add model to database without losing data

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a simple Django website (just a form, really) which asks a few questions and saves the data in a SQL database using Model.save(). Pretty simple. I want to add a model to do page counting, though -- it'll just be a single object with a field that gets incremented each time the page's view function is called.

Now, I know little to nothing about SQL. I imagine this is not terribly difficult to do, but I would like to avoid losing or breaking all my data because of a slight misunderstanding of how the database works. So how can I go about doing this? I've heard of some third-party apps that will implement such functionality, but I'd like to do it myself just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why your existing data would be affected at all. You're talking about adding a completely new table to the database, which is supported within Django by simply running `manage.py syncdb`. The case where that doesn't work is when you're modifying existing tables, but you're not doing that here.

I must say though that learning and using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) would be of benefit in any case. It's good practice to have a tool that can maintain your model tables.

(Plus, of course, you would never lose any data, because your database is backed up, right? Right?)

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. I didn't realize that syncdb wouldn't reset everything.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding new model, you can just run [syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) and it will create new table for your model. If you were to change existing model, then you'd need to manually update database schema using "ALTER TABLE" statements or use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) instead.